# Displaying summary stats for DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I find the summary statistics for a DataFrame (using a dataset from a CSV file)?  I tried creating a new DataFrame and pulling the data from the csv file but I think there’s a shorter way. Plus, I already previewed the first five rows of the csv file so I do not want to reinvent the wheel if I can help it.

Comment: from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) of `df.describe`: *Generates descriptive statistics that summarize the central tendency, dispersion and shape of a dataset’s distribution*. If that's not what you're going for, you'll have to be more specific!

Comment: Thank you! I used this resource as well, but there it didn’t explain a way to .describe() without creating a new dataframe with dictionaries. Is there a way to find the summary stats of a csv file?